# Fast and robust way to detect a reflective ball

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a highly reflective ball in an image that looks like this:

[image]

What is a robust method to detect the ball in real-time? (5-10 FPS)

I tried several segmentation algorithms, but they fail to separate the ball from the background and instead cut the ball into pieces, as there are many different areas on the ball itself.

Due to the reflective nature, a simple circular hough transform does not work well. The same goes for any simple treshhold or morphological operation.

Do you have any advice for handling reflective surfaces in general?

Comment: Might be a better fit for https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: hough transform should work well. the edge contrast is pretty good. maybe you do something wrong.

Comment: @joelsa, could you host a video sample?

Comment: @m3h0w I do not intend to use a video later on, but rather single frames shot at some frequency using a Raspberry Pi. The reason I said 5-10 FPS is because the application is time-critical, so 100-200ms processing time is something I do not wish to exceed.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought maybe Optical Flow would provide some interesting results, since the reflections might move differently than the environment.

Comment: if the [specular highlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_highlight) is always there, you can detect it as a maximum in the saturation channel, so you can get an idea about where the ball could be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) suggestion is great, as long as you have a rough idea of how the ball will move in the frame and therefore roughly what minimum, maximum radius you account for:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv

img = cv2.imread('wcEXm.jpg',0)


#Method 1: Hough Circles
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]])
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,dp=1,minDist=50,param1=127,param2=30,minRadius=50,maxRadius=150)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
```

[image: Hough Circles]

Another option is to use [findContours()](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html). With the right options and bit of filtering (e.g. `dilate()`, `erode()`) you can segment the ball from the background and the ratio between the width and height (closer to a square) will help.

[image: dilated and eroded threshold]

However, there's one neat little thing that might simplify this a lot if you're not interested in the size of the ball, just knowing where it is.
You're ball is reflective and to even begin to detect you will need a source of light, therefore, even though colours/environments will look different, the ball will have a highlight. Assuming the source of light isn't in the frame, your reflective ball will probably be the next brightest thing in the scene:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('wcEXm.jpg',0)

minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(img)
cv2.circle(img, maxLoc, 20, (0,192,0),10)
```

[image: minMaxLoc]

In terms of performance on RaspberryPi, I recommend the following:

1. Use Adrian's [tutorial on using PiCam with OpenCV in Python](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/)
2. If you plan to use `minMaxLoc()` or other functions that work with grayscale images you can use the [`'yuv'`](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/recipes2.html#unencoded-image-capture-yuv-format) colour space and simply use the Y (luminance) channel to save a bit of time not needing to convert from RGB to lumma/grayscale
3. Use a smaller resolution (e.g. 320x240 or 160x120). You can scale the result back up if you need to map the x,y position of the ball to something else.

**Update:**
Yet another thing that might help is [Canny edge detection](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) because the scene is simple and the ball will stand out:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
```

[image: Canny Edge Detection]

[image: Canny Edge Contours]